# Windows Phone 7 resolution - Is my emulator lying to me?

Tags: windows-phone-7

All the talk on WP7 resolution = 800x480. I can create more than 480 and it shows up in the emulator - I just don't know if this means I do have more screen space than is promulgated or if my emulator is lying to me.

Putting a Silverlight app in Landscape only mode (`SupportedOrientations="Landscape" Orientation="Landscape"` in `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage />`). I'll have a width of 800 and height of 480 (`d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="480"`).

I change `d:DesignHeight` to `d:DesignHeight="496"` and then add as the only XAML inside the `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage />` tag:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Blue">
    <TextBlock Text="bottom" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

See there? My "Bottom" text is still showing on the screen. Anything thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your "design" sizes will be overridden at runtime. Your emulator isn't lying but your designer is (now) misleading.

You can data-bind some labels to `ActualWidth` and `Actualheight` to verify what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have `mc:Ignorable="d"` set as an attribute on the page, `d:DesignHeight="496"` only applies in the designer, it does not affect what happens on the emulator or device.